# How to switch between two activities in android?

Tags: java, android

Hi I have two fragment activities? the main activity launches the second activity? now I have two switch between these very often.

In normal activity this is not possible. if i switch from the second activity to Main activity  the second activity pops up from the stack and gets destroyed. here with fragment activity is this possible? if so how to achieve this?

In details after launching the main activity and by pressing a button on the main activity i launch the second fragment activity. then i have moved to the main fragment activity using back key on android phone but now i want to go back to the second fragment activity that i launched by pressing the button on the main activity. kindly help?

The following is my code:-

The following is the mainifest file.

```
    <application android:allowBackup="true" >
    <activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:name="com.ymd.ipmsg.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:name="com.ymd.ipmsg.activities.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"
        android:parentActivityName="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

The following is my activity_chat.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"   >

<fragment android:name="com.ymd.ipmsg.fragments.DeviceFragmentTB"
          android:id="@+id/tb_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The following is my activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"   >

<fragment android:name="com.ymd.ipmsg.fragments.DeviceFragmentTB"
          android:id="@+id/tb_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The following is my device_frag.ml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/device_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/device_name" 
    android:textIsSelectable="true" 
    android:tag="name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/device"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/device_type" 
    android:textIsSelectable="true" 
    android:tag="device"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ipadd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/device_ip" 
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:tag="ipadd" />  

    </LinearLayout>
```

The eollowing is my DeviceFragmentTB.java

```
    package com.ymd.ipmsg.fragments;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.ymd.ipmsg.activities.ChatActivity;
    import com.ymd.ipmsg.main.R;

    public class DeviceFragmentTB extends Fragment  {

private Boolean flag=true;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_frag, container, false); 
    TextView nameView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    nameView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent)   ;


        }
    });
    view.findViewById(R.id.device_layout).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if(flag){
                View deviceLayout = getView().findViewById(R.id.device_layout);
                int deviceFragWidth=deviceLayout.getWidth();
                int eachViewWidth=deviceFragWidth/3;                    
                TextView nameView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
                nameView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                nameView.setTextSize(25);
                nameView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                nameView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                nameView.setWidth(eachViewWidth);
                TextView deviceView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.device);
                deviceView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                deviceView.setTextSize(25);
                deviceView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                deviceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                deviceView.setWidth(eachViewWidth);
                TextView ipaddView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.ipadd);
                ipaddView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                ipaddView.setTextSize(25);
                ipaddView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                ipaddView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                ipaddView.setWidth(eachViewWidth);                      
                flag=false;
                System.out.println("ok sir");
            }               
        }
    });

    return view;
}   

    }
```

The following is my MainActivity.java

```
    package com.ymd.ipmsg.main;


    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.ymd.ipmsg.activities.ChatActivity;
    import com.ymd.ipmsg.fragments.DeviceFragment;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements DeviceFragment.DeviceFragmentListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
   // setupActionBar();

}   


@Override
public void onDeviceSelected(View view){
    String ip=null;
    if(((String)view.getTag()).equalsIgnoreCase("ipadd")){
        TextView tv=(TextView)view;
        ip=tv.getText().toString();
    }else{
        LinearLayout llo=(LinearLayout)view.getParent();
        TextView tv= (TextView)llo.getChildAt(2);
        ip=tv.getText().toString();
    }       
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Window win=getWindow();     
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp=win.getAttributes();
    wlp.gravity=Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    wlp.x=10;
    wlp.y=10;
    wlp.width=200;
    wlp.height=400;
    win.setAttributes(wlp);

}

    }
```

The following is my chat activity   ChatActiviy.java

```
    package com.ymd.ipmsg.activities;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    import com.ymd.ipmsg.main.R;

    public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //setupActionBar();
}



@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Window win=getWindow();     
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp=win.getAttributes();
    wlp.gravity=Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    wlp.x=10;
    wlp.y=450;
    wlp.width=200;
    wlp.height=400;
    win.setAttributes(wlp);

}

   }
```

Comment: i don't know what you want to say.but see my ans below

Comment: put your both fragment in one activity only then you can see both fragment in a same time...read more about fragments

Comment: So even with fragment activities keeping two activities on the screen is not possible? is it? first i have developed my code for my requirement with activities and i have observed that keeping both activities on the screen is not possible and when asked here for solution all the people said that fragments can solve this. so i have done the code again with fragment activities but it is the same case with framentactivity as well. sure i will try with some other approach using fragments but initially i thought we can retain 2 fragment activities on the screen. I think this is not possible at all.

Comment: murali we ll see this tomorrow .tell me your exact requirement ..send me mail related this ...

Comment: I dont see your email id in your profile.

Comment: I have done the complete study of fragments. I saw on the internet posts saying that we can run 2-3 activities parlely so this statements confused me. I found that running 2-3 activities and switching between them is not possible but how ever when fragments used we can run multiple layouts(activity xml files) in a single action and work with them dynamically by adding, hiding, replacing them. Any ways thanks for your all your help. I am abeginer in android. so lot many doubts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch from

1`-A -> B` (both are activity)

use this on Button click

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

2- `B -> A`

use this on Button Click

```
finish()
```

couse `finish()` will finish your current activity . and you will get screen what you have previous

Comment: I dont want to destroy the second activity. i need to switch between them often. i want to retain both.  without calling finish() on the second activity is it possible to switc from B---> A and later point of time i want to come back to A ---> B

Comment: try first murali...this is for switching only

Comment: sorry if i am confusing you. I have two screens which shows the progress of some back end activities. so i need to see both the screens how much progress have been made by switching them often or may be flipping them? if i destroy the second screen and come back to first screen then how do i see the progress that is happening on the second screen at later point of time? If i use finish() on the second activity, i will come back to the previous but then if i have to go back i have to freshly launch the second activity by using start() which starts again as it has lost all the progress it made.

Comment: Hi cogar, I have submitted the code. please have a look. I also have posted a comment on the 2nd solution as that is also not working. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have two activity A and B. 
In your menifest file just add this

```
        <activity
        android:name=".B"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

It will works fine. Thanks.

Comment: LOL ..he is able to moved A->B ,it meands he already add this thing in manifest.

Comment: I have submitted the code. I have done what u said but it appears the same as the case of normal activity. The first activity launched. then by pressing the first label that appears on the activity i have launched the second activity. the second activity comes into focus. now when i move to the first activity, the first activity gains focus. once the first activity gains focus. the second activity disappears from the screen. I want to retain both of them in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong, Android does not destroy an `activity` if you navigate to a second activity. It does not call it's `onDestroy` method simply because a new activity get's brought to the foreground.